# Resources for Material Setups

Tags: node-editor

I've been exploring various resources for creating materials in Blender, including  libraries such as BlenderKit and numerous instructional videos on YouTube. However, I am looking for a more straightforward approach for quick reference.

I'm searching for a website or online resource that focuses specifically on Blender material setups through just screenshots of node configurations. My goal is to understand different materials' node setups at a glance without delving into full tutorials or videos.

Does anyone know of such a resource that primarily showcases material node setups?

PS- I'm not looking for tutorials! I have not found any resource that focuses on node setup by providing a gallery at [Resources for Blender topic.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)